# GitLab CI can't access Vault

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault, vault

GitLab Community Edition 14.2.7

```
curl -s -k -X GET https://gitlab.domain.com/-/jwks
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"xUeI9jobL................194Xg0gj5DSct8O__KR6I8RoTTBACp1lRYSlBO4w","use":"sig","alg":"RS256"}]}
```

**In Vault:**

Created a secret:
`vault kv put secret/projects/test/mariadb login=user password=pass`

Created a policy:

```
vault policy write project-test - <<EOF
path "secret/projects/test/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]
}
EOF
```

And created a JWT role:

```
vault write auth/jwt/role/project-test - <<EOF
{
  "role_type": "jwt",
  "policies": ["project-test"],
  "token_explicit_max_ttl": 60,
  "user_claim": "my@mail.com",
  "bound_claims": {
    "project_id": "321",
    "ref": "main",
    "ref_type": "branch"
  }
}
EOF
```

```
vault write auth/jwt/config jwks_url="https://gitlab.domain.com/-/jwks" bound_issuer="gitlab.domain.com"
```

project_id is correct, main branch.

**In GitLab CI:**

```
stages:
  - test_vault

test:
  stage: test_vault
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - export VAULT_ADDR=https://k8s.domain.com:8700
    - export VAULT_TOKEN="$(vault write -field=token auth/jwt/login role=project-test jwt=$CI_JOB_JWT)"
    - export LOGIN="$(vault kv get -field=login secret/projects/test/mariadb)"
    - export PASSWORD="$(vault kv get -field=password secret/projects/test/mariadb)"
    - echo $LOGIN
    - echo $PASSWORD
```

At the output, I get 403 everywhere. Where does it not give access? The Vault logs are silent.

```
$ export VAULT_ADDR=https://k8s.domain.com:8700
$ export VAULT_TOKEN="$(vault write -field=token auth/jwt/login role=project-test jwt=$CI_JOB_JWT)"
Error writing data to auth/jwt/login: Error making API request.
URL: PUT https://k8s.domain.com:8700/v1/auth/jwt/login
Code: 400. Errors:
* claim "my@mail.com" not found in token
```

I see that it swears at `claim "my@mail.com" not found in token`, but it's not clear where to get the correct user_claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authorization policy for the GitlabCI role with JWT/OIDC authentication is slightly wrong. It appears that you replaced the `user_email` with a literal email address. That value was not a placeholder, but rather an instruction for Vault to associate the token with the associated email of the user triggering the authentication:

```
{
  "role_type": "jwt",
  "policies": ["project-test"],
  "token_explicit_max_ttl": 60,
  "user_claim": "user_email",
  "bound_claims": {
    "project_id": "321",
    "ref": "main",
    "ref_type": "branch"
  }
}
```

There may be another issue after this one, but the rest of your configuration LGTM, and this will move you past your current blocker.

Comment: Hello. I specified user_mail and the error disappeared. Thank you!